# go get sys: textflag.h missing

Tags: go

I am trying to use the "sys" package in a go program. So I did

```
go get golang.org/x/sys/unix
```

and got

```
# golang.org/x/sys/unix
src/golang.org/x/sys/unix/asm.s:6 6a: No such file or directory: textflag.h
```

I am on Fedora 20, using 
    go version go1.3.3 linux/amd64

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I googled the error and and found [this](https://github.com/docker/docker-network/issues/2) and [this](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=9211) which seem to imply you need go1.4 to build it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sys package was introduced as a replacement for syscall in go 1.4, I would assume that it doesn't work in versions prior to 1.4.

if you cannot upgrade, look at the syscall package to see if it meets your needs.